# Adobe flex createPopUp() opening same instances when clicked

Tags: flex4, flex4.5

I'm new to Adobe Flex. I have 3 different fields consisting of three pop up buttons. When I click on one of the pop up button on my web page multiple times, I can see multiple instances of popups being opened.

I want to display only once when the pop up button is clicked.

```
    public static var myPopUp:MyPopUpClass;


    public static function openClosePopUp(open:Boolean, list:ArrayCollection = null, formComponent:UIComponent = null, mouseEvent:MouseEvent = null):void {
if (open) {
    myPopUp = MyPopUpClass(PopUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication 
     as DisplayObject, MyPopUpClass, false));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid opening the same popup multiple times, you could replace

```
if (open) {
```

by

```
if (open && !myPopUp) {
```